# Trigger a macro when a cell changes

Tags: vba, excel

I know there are tonnes of questions and answers, but I've got a very rudimentary knowledge of programming in VBA and I'm having a frustrating time making things work.

I have a sheet that has 1000 rows of employees, and each row starts with the name of their manager. i.e. column A has the manager names, columns B, C, D, etc have other info.

My current macro looks at the text in cell **J1** and compares it with the text in column A. **J1** populates from another worksheet using an "=worksheet1!A1" type thing.

```
Sub hiderows()

BeginRow = 2
EndRow = 1000
ChkCol = 1

For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow

If Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value = Cells(1, "J") Then
Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = False
Else
Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
Next RowCnt
End Sub
```

What I'm trying to get is for this to run automatically when the value of **J1** changes (i.e. from Tim to Jake). I've found some code to do that, but i can't get it to work.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("$J$1")) Is Nothing Then

        Application.Run _

'your macro here

End If
End Sub
```

how do I add my macro? do I keep the End Sub in mine so there are two End Subs? My macro is stored in the same excel book in Module1

Any help combining these in to a workable one would be great, I'm pulling my hair out here...

Comment: Okay, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        For i = 2 To 1000
            Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = (Cells(i, 1).Value = Range("J1").Value)
        Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to do anything. I added it as a Worksheet module (right click, view code) but it doesn't seem to change anything. The first macro I pasted works perfectly to hide the rows based on the name in **J1**, I just want to automate it to run whenever the contents of **J1** change.

Comment: Add a breakpoint to the code and you will see it being triggered on each change. If it doesn't trigger then check that `Application.EnableEvents` is set to `True`

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I just don't get it. I used 'toggle breakpoint' from the Debug menu and I guess that added a breakpoint. I don't know where to look for Application.EnableEvents. In my list of Properties for the sheet I have some Enable<whatever> options, but EnableEvents is not one of them listed. A search for that in Excel doesn't bring up anything either. It may be time to cut my losses and just trigger the hiderows macro manually. Thanks for trying!

Comment: I think I just realised my problem... the text in the target cell doesn't actually change, it is always "=Snapshot!B1", because it is displaying a name from another worksheet... so VBA isn't seeing any actual cell contents change.

Comment: Use the `Calculate()` event instead - see edit above.

Comment: That throws a Runtime '424' error on    If Target.Address = "$J$1" Then    I'll mark this as the answer as I'm sure it's right, and my inability to get this to work reflects more on me and the way I've got this workbook set up. Thanks for trying, @Macro Man!

Comment: "Out of Stack Space" error is thrown and then excel becomes unresponsive. When I debut it it highlights "Next" in yellow. Giving up on this for now and going home, but really thank you.

Comment: Another edit - try disabling/re-enabling events, looks like hiding a row triggers the sheet calculation which I didn't foresee.

Comment: Looks like that worked! Thanks for your persistence!